# Cannot select item from ItemTemplate

Tags: jquery, listview

I can't select the `tr`, I tried to use: `$("#itemRow")`, special class selector, `$("tr[itemID]")` - nothing worked.

I am guessing it is because of the ItemTemplate:

```
<ItemTemplate>

<tr runat="server" id="itemRow" class='xxx' itemID='<%# Eval("ID") %>'>
<td><%# Eval("ID") %></td>
<td><%# Eval("Caption") %></td>
<td><%# Eval("Visible") %></td>
</tr>
<tr><td style="height:1px;"></td></tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: where are your <table> tags?

Comment: @GintasK, they're probably in the headertemplate and footertemplate tags

Comment: gintas thanks but with or without the table tag - doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would check if your ID you set for that specific row is still available on the client side. To do so, open that website or piece of html in your browser, use your mouse: right click on the row and "inspect element" (you might want to use Chrome or FireFox to do so)

If your ID is really in the HTML it is probably a timing problem. which means that you want to select the DOM element (in this case your tr) before it got rendered.